# Posting a form using AJAX,node/express and mongoDB(mongoose) reach the server but don't pass the content

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I have a form and a AJAX script in my HTML

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <textarea name="message" id="message">Some content here...</textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
******
<script>
    (function(){
         var xhr;
         var data=document.getElementById('myForm');
         data.addEventListener('submit',makeRequest);

         function makeRequest(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             var formData=new FormData(data);

             xhr= new XMLHttpRequest()
             xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                 if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status===200) {
                     console.log(xhr.response)
                   }
                          };
             xhr.open('POST','/api/clicks',true);
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
             xhr.send(formData);
               }
      })()
</script>
```

The /api/clicks resource is loaded in a index.js file within the /app/routes folder.

```
app.route('/api/clicks')
            .post(clickHandler.addClick)
```

And the object and method clickHandler.addClick is in a controller file clickHandler.server.js that makes the queries to mongo.

```
function clickHandler(){
       this.addClick=function(req,res){
             Clicks /*This is the model defined in other file
                      new Schema({text:String})*/
                  .create({text: req.body}, function (err, res) {
                   if (err) return err;
                         console.log("saved!")
                    })
            }
     }
```

The server is in a server.js file.

```
var express=require('express')
var bodyParser=require("body-parser")
var routes=require('./app/routes/index.js')
var mongoose=require('mongoose')

var app=express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(function (req, res) {
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
   res.write('you posted:\n')
   res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
mongoose.connect(....)
routes(app)
app.listen(3000)
```

It seems the post works as the console mark saved! and a check in the mongo console indicates that a new document is been added, but only the first two fields by default (__id and __v), nothing about the text of the form.(?).Also a check in the google dev tools-network displayed the text of the form in the Form Data of the Headers.

Comment: try checking what's inside `req.body`, I suspect it doesn't contain a string to be inserted to `text`. It might be a JSON, try `console.log(req.body)` to see whats inside of it, and report back :)

Comment: @Airwavezx my thoughts, exactly. Perhaps OP meant to try `req.body.message`?
Also, the `body-parser` middleware configured for form encoded data must be mounted before the route handler

Comment: `console.log(req.body)` returns undefined.

Comment: are you using bodyParser in app.js ?

Comment: Not, I will do it and come back later

Comment: I updated the above code with the file `server.js`, where I placed the bodyParser as middleware `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`.It doesn't work, the `req.body` in the controller file clickHandler.server.js returns undefined.

Comment: @user1881983 what do you see when you `console.log(req)` ?

Comment: `[object Object]` with console.log(req)